# Add next/prev buttons to the help center

Tags: feature-request, help-center

I just looked through the [help pages](http://docs-beta.stackexchange.com/help/bounty) and noticed that they don't have any next/previous button at the bottom of the page.

[image]

It would be really nice to have those buttons, so users are more likely to page through the whole thing (because it's *so* hard to scroll up and see that menu on the right ;). To be clear, I'm imagining this working on individual sections, such as `Reputation & Moderation` and `Asking`.

Comment: If the help pages could be read as a book I would see a usability benefit but not all topics have a logical *next* or *previous*, I wonder if they cause confusion when implemented.

Comment: @rene If it encourages more net reading of the help pages, we'll probably be better off.

Comment: Stop bumping with useless edits. This is abuse of the edit mechanism. Edit only if you have **something to improve or add**.